# I Want to Choose batch id which has two selected course offered from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, qsqlquery

I Have a batch subject table relation like below, From this table I want to 
Choose the batch which has providing both subjects 3 and 2

```
batch_id | subject_id

   1     |     3

   2     |     3

   3     |     2

   2     |     4

   4     |     1

   1     |     2
```

I would like to get the result as like below because the batch_id 1 only providing both subjects 3 and 2

```
batch_id
   1
```

I did a lot of search about this I can't find a better solution for this. if you think this is a duplicate question means please provide help links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT batch_id
FROM `YourTable`
WHERE subject_id IN(2,3)
GROUP BY batch_id
HAVING COUNT(subject_id)=2
```

Comment: Thank you bro.  You saved my time

Comment: @SeeganSee the best way to say thank you on SO is to accept the answer ;)